# How do I display multiple array images in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a screen that is expected to display images from an array in a list builder. I have the following code but where I am trying to display images according to the index but no image is displayed.

```
List<String> imageNames = [
  'a1.jpg',
  'a2.jpg',
  'a3.jpg',
  'a4.jpg',
  'a5.png',
  'a6.jpg',
  'a7.jpg',
  'a8.jpg',
  'a9.jpg',
  'a10.jpg',
  'a11.jpg'
];

return Scaffold(
  body: new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: imageNames.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return new Padding(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 10.0),
        child: new Card(
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
          ),
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Image.asset("assets/images/" + imageNames[index]),
              new Text('a'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

This is the .yaml file

```
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/a1.jpg
    - assets/images/a2.jpg
    - assets/images/a3.jpg
    - assets/images/a4.jpg
    - assets/images/a5.png
    - assets/images/a6.jpg
    - assets/images/a7.jpg
    - assets/images/a9.jpg
    - assets/images/a10.jpg
    - assets/images/a11.jpg


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
```

How do I display the images? Only the text a is displayed 10 times.
When I debug the app, I am taken to this code in image_provider.dart.

**image_provider.dart**

```
 @protected
  Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(AssetBundleImageKey key, DecoderCallback decode) async {
    ByteData? data;
    // Hot reload/restart could change whether an asset bundle or key in a
    // bundle are available, or if it is a network backed bundle.
    try {
      data = await key.bundle.load(key.name);
    } on FlutterError {
      PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.evict(key);
      rethrow;//breakpoint
    }
    if (data == null) {
      PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.evict(key);
      throw StateError('Unable to read data');
    }
    return decode(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you properly defined all the image assets in the pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: @AkassharjunShanmugarajahall the images are correctly defined

Comment: Try killing the app and run. In case if you are trying to hot reload after adding an asset. Also, add your .yaml image asset code and a screenshot of your image source.

Comment: your code is working just fine in my end, I think you need to check your pubspec.yaml file carefully.and then hot reload or restart the run again as @davidkihara stated

Answer (score -1):

Try changing to:

```yaml
  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/
```

More specific example:

```yaml
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
   assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/
```